# Is development of Ubuntu phone on other platforms possible?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

When I first read about Ubuntu phone I became very excited about it. However, I am disappointed to see that if I want to get started I should download and install Ubuntu first. While I can totally understand this (it's pretty much the same with Windows phone and iOS), I prefer Debian on desktop and I don't want to get rid of it, although I couldn't find the qml toolkit for Debian, nor Windows.
Is there any chance that developer tools will be released for the above mentioned platforms?

Comment: Why wouldn't they work on Debian?

Comment: Why the heck would an Ubuntu developer create a Windows toolkit? Let them create it if they want it. But ... why would it not work on Debian? Please elaborate ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind Why wouldn't an Ubuntu developer create a Windows toolkit? There's a Windows toolkit for Android. If we take Ubuntu for Phones seriously as something that will be a major mobile OS used around the world, there's no reason to think it should have any less developer support than other major platforms like Android. (And it's not like Canonical shies away from making Windows software--there's an official Ubuntu One client for Windows, after all.)

Comment: That was created by a Windows developer @EliahKagan ;) (might have been an employee of Canonical but he was a windows developer ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu can be installed in a virtual machine on other platforms already. Since Ubuntu is free, this is the easiest path to get into Ubuntu development if you can't switch platform.

Failing this, [Ubuntu will always be free](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy), so any developer tools released as part of Ubuntu can always be ported to other platforms by developers if they wish.

But let's be realistic: who's going to bother to do it, and with what motivation? Nothing is stopping anyone, but I can't see it happening.